# How to get an records with each month in a date range of two fields?

Tags: django

I have a study year model which has a start and end date.

```
class StudyYear(models.Model):
   date_begin = models.DateField(...)
   date_end = models.DateField(...)
```

I need a Queryset in which there are records for each study year with a month in its date range (start_date:end_date)

Example:
For the study year (09/01/2022:01/02/2023), qs should contain records:

```
...
(code=9_2022, name='September 2022'),
(code=10_2022, name='November 2022'),
(code=11_2022, name='October 2022'),
(code=12_2022, name='December 2022'),
(code=1_2023, name='January 2023'),
(code=2_2023, name='February 2023'),
...
```

Honestly, I have no idea how to solve this problem, I really hope for your help!

UPD:
I already have Queryset with required studt years, for example, for simplicity it contains one record:

```
Queryset(StudyYear{id=1, date_begin='09/01/2022', date_end='02/01/2023'})
```

I need to get records like:

```
Queryset([
    StudyYear{id=1, date_begin='09/01/2022', date_end='02/01/2023', code='9_2022', name='September 2022'}
    StudyYear{id=1, date_begin='09/01/2022', date_end='02/01/2023', code='10_2022', name='October 2022'}
    StudyYear{id=1, date_begin='09/01/2022', date_end='02/01/2023', code='11_2022', name='November 2022'}
    StudyYear{id=1, date_begin='09/01/2022', date_end='02/01/2023', code='12_2022', name='December 2022'}
    StudyYear{id=1, date_begin='09/01/2022', date_end='02/01/2023', code='1_2023', name='January 2023'}
    StudyYear{id=1, date_begin='09/01/2022', date_end='02/01/2023', code='2_2023', name='February 2023'}
    ])
```

Comment: Do you also need to sum up all records of the same month making it into one?

Comment: @DivyaPrakash, no, I only need a qs of all records, preferably only unique ones

Comment: you want records for only these 5 months?

Comment: @DivyaPrakash, I want to get all months in begin_date and date_end range, for each study year in one qs

Comment: Can you please check the answer, and let me know if the approach works?

Comment: @DivyaPrakash, Unfortunately, this method did not solve the problem, most likely I did not quite accurately explain its essence. I have updated the description in the question. I'm expecting a query result of duplicate qs of each entry having a different (month, year) pair. The API of my UI component accepts qs as storage, in particular this component should allow you to select a month from the appropriate study years.